# Double integrals by iteration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the double integrals by interation.

$\iint_{R}^{}xy^2dA$, where R is the finite region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$.

The answer is $3/56$.

My work:
The interception between $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$ is (0,0) and (1,1).
$$\int_{0}^{1}(xy^2)dx=\left [ \frac{x^2y^2}{2} \right ]_{0}^{1}=\frac{y^2}{2}\\
\int_{0}^{1}(\frac{y^2}{2})dy=\left [ \frac{y^3}{6} \right ]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Well, obviously $\frac{1}{6}\neq\frac{3}{56}$. What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the zone between the two curves is inside the square [0,1]x[0,1], but if you fix $x\in[0,1]$ then the $y$ 'moves' only between $x^{2}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ (you can check that easily by drawing the curves that delimit R), so the integral is

$$\int{\int_{R}{xy^{2}}}dA=\int_{0}^{1}({\int_{x^{2}}^{\sqrt{x}}{xy^{2}}dy})dx$$

The same can be done for $y\in[0,1]$, and then $x$ 'moves' between $y^{2}$ and $\sqrt{y}$, so the integral can be written

$$\int{\int_{R}{xy^{2}}}dA=\int_{0}^{1}({\int_{y^{2}}^{\sqrt{y}}{xy^{2}}dx})dy$$

(This can be done because of Fubini's theorem, and because the function is integrable in all of the intervals that appear above)

What you have done is the integral in all of the square [0,1]x[0,1], that's why the result is different.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me understand it.